# directive to enable keyboard-navigation (using tab)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, frontend, keyboard-navigation

Hi I have this div which is skipped when we press tab, other UI elements come into focus but not this one, Which directive do I need to add to this so that it comes into focus when we navigate UI using keyboard

```html
<div class="vertical-menu">       
  <a ng-class="{active: Page == 'homeview'}" ng-click="Page = 'homeview'">
    Home
  </a>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are html elements without tabindex enabled by default, and the div element is one of these.

To enable it, you must set the ***tabindex*** attribute to something >= 0:

```
<div tabindex="0"> ... </div>
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) you can find more information.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me I'll go through the documentation for better understanding.